# Java Print String using descending java Hash Map

Tags: java, string, hashmap

Lets say I have a string "aaabcccdddd"
I have stored each alphabets as keys and each repetition of the character as the value in a hash map. How can I use the map to print out to my console the characters in a descending order. For example= "dddcccaaab"

```
void str(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    Map<Character, Integer> elements = new HashMap<>(Math.min(len, 26));
    Map<Character, Integer> sortedByValues;

    String concact="";        int b;char a;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
        if (!elements.containsKey(s.charAt(i)))
            elements.put(s.charAt(i), 1);
        else
            elements.put(s.charAt(i), elements.get(s.charAt(i)) + 1);}
```

Comment: show us some code to explain better what you are wanting to do.

Comment: You say you have created a hash map, I presume you did that in code?

Comment: *string a= "abbcccddd" count a=2; count b=2, count c=3; count d=4;* **This does not make sense**

Comment: Hey I dont really have code that best describes my situation. So i hope this helps- 
string a= "babcdcdcd";
count a=a; count b=2, count c=3; count d=4;

im storing these values in a hash map (basically how many times each alphabet appears, assuming no spaces or non-alphabets)

I need to print out my highest occuring alphabet, which is d=4 and then go down the order

and my final output should be a SORTED form of the initial string returned in descending order like this- "ddddcccbba"

Comment: This is the code I have used. i just need to figure out how to sort and then print it in descending order-



void str(String s) {
        int len = s.length();
        Map<Character, Integer> elements = new HashMap<>(Math.min(len, 26));
        Map<Character, Integer> sortedByValues;

        String concact="";        int b;char a;
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
            if (!elements.containsKey(s.charAt(i)))
                elements.put(s.charAt(i), 1);
            else
                elements.put(s.charAt(i), elements.get(s.charAt(i)) + 1);}

Comment: @LazimSharar If you are sure the input is alphabetic then a simplistic approach would be to go with a primitive array to store the counts and later on process the array from the end to get your output.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/sort-a-mapkey-value-by-values-java as how to sort a map by value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting the `HashMap` to a `TreeMap`:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String test = "aaabcccdddd";
    Map<String, Long> hashMap = 
      Arrays.stream(test.split("")).
      collect(Collectors.groupingBy(c -> c, Collectors.counting()));
    // System.out.println(hashMap); // {a=3, b=1, c=3, d=4}
    Map<String, Long> treeMap = new TreeMap(Collections.reverseOrder());
    treeMap.putAll(hashMap);
    // System.out.println(treeMap); // {d=4, c=3, b=1, a=3}
    for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : treeMap.entrySet()) {
      for(int i = 0; i < entry.getValue(); i++) {
        System.out.print(entry.getKey());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
ddddcccbaaa
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/FbIv/1)

Comment: is there any way to make sure that order is always descending?

Comment: That is the reason for the `TreeMap`